# How to build PostgreSQL with openSSL support in yocto?

Tags: postgresql, openssl, embedded-linux, yocto, timescaledb

I am currently working on a Yocto Project. I have to embed timescaledb in my custom layer which further depends on postgresql which I have used from the meta-openembedded. The postgresql version I have is **10.5**. Here is the link to it: https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/af8dd46f862e84af4e2feb32207e5822e44f23fc/meta-oe/recipes-dbs/postgresql

When I build with this configuration, I get the error from timescaledb's **CMakeLists.txt** file:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:315 (message):
>   |   PostgreSQL was built without OpenSSL support, which TimescaleDB needs for
>   |   full compatibility.  Please rebuild PostgreSQL using `--with-openssl` or if
>   |   you want to continue without OpenSSL, re-run bootstrap with
>   |   `-DUSE_OPENSSL=0`

I am using timescaledb **version 1.5.1**. The source can be found here: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb .
Trying to resolve this I added a **postgresql_%.bbappend** to enable the OpenSSL support. But I still get the same error.

My project structure for the custom layer:

```
├── meta-test
    ├── recipes-dbs
        ├── timescaledb
        │   └── timescaledb.bb
        ├── postgres
            └── postgresql_%.bbappend
```

**timescaledb.bb** file:

```
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE-APACHE;md5=2ee41112a44fe7014dce33e26468ba93"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/archive/1.5.1.tar.gz"

DEPENDS += "postgresql"
inherit cmake
```

**postgresql_%.bbappend** file. I created this to enable the --with-openssl option.

```
PACKAGECONFIG += "openssl uuid"
```

Any suggestions how can I resolve this?

Comment: https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/af8dd46f862e84af4e2feb32207e5822e44f23fc/meta-oe/recipes-dbs/postgresql/postgresql.inc#L58 already sets openssl in packageconfig, so your bbappend is ineffective. but https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L312-L318 is a runtime check, not compile time check so it fails obviously in a cross compiled environment. it will be better to replace it with some other way to detect openssl support in postgresql. Perhaps just remove that check and hardcode the PG_CONFIGURE_FLAGS would work